# Normalise dataframe (remove data redundancy and create lookup tables)

Tags: python, r

I have some awareness of data normalisation techniques as applied to relational databases such as SQL. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

I am very interested in applying these techniques to flat files (csv) obtained from various sources.

Are there any specific packages or techniques that would help to obtain columns which are functionally redundant and help with reshuffling my data? Possibly finding all interdependent variables (perhaps perfectly correlated?), stripping them out and copying them elsewhere as a lookup table.

Solutions in R preferred as it's our team's main tool, but Python would also be OK.

```
example

| Product | Class | Class 2 | Sales |
| A       | Red   | Large   | 12    |
| A       | Red   | Large   | 42    |
| B       | Blue  | Small   | 12    |
```

Let product A always be Red and Large. B is always Blue and small. So a better way of storing said data would be:

```
Table 1            Lookup Table
| A | 12 |         | A | Red  | Large |
| A | 42 |         | B | Blue | Small |
| B | 12 |
```

Comment: "finding all interdependent variables" is a tall order. Also, perfect correlation does not mean its coming from a relation; it could just be that your sample is too small to see the relevant variation. Generally, I'd expect that you should know which vars vary with which keys.

Comment: Hey Frank, I appreciate that this isn't an easy task to do programmatically. However, lets say this needs to be done with data for new clients, pretty regularly. "Knowing the data" takes time and can be time consuming (I didn't create it, db admins aren't necessarily available). Some form of programmatic assistance in finding some of the columns matching those specifications would undoubtedly be of good use.

Comment: hi hi, are you trying to normalize each flat file on its own or do you also want to find the inter-dependencies between multiple files?

Comment: Good question. I'd say mainly the former, as a solution for that would likely entail a solution for the latter too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a rather broad question which also invites opinionated answers.

However, my answer consists of four parts:

1. read the data file(s)
2. identify redundant columns
3. separate the data
4. combine (join, merge) when needed

While [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43819705/3817004) already has shown how to do step 3 using base R and there are other alternatives (`sqldf`, `tidyverse`) available I recommend to use the `data.table` package for performance reasons when dealing with large volumes of data.

#### Step 1: Read data

Here, we simulate reading data from a character string but `fread()` will read files as well:

```
DT <- fread(
  "| Product | Class | Class_2 | Sales |
| A       | Red   | Large   | 12    |
| A       | Red   | Large   | 42    |
| B       | Blue  | Small   | 12    |
| B       | Blue  | Small   | 22    |
| C       | Blue  | Large   | 59    |
",
  sep = "|"
)[, Product:Sales]

DT
#   Product Class Class_2 Sales
#1:       A   Red   Large    12
#2:       A   Red   Large    42
#3:       B  Blue   Small    12
#4:       B  Blue   Small    22
#5:       C  Blue   Large    59
```

Note that rows have been added w.r.t. the OP's sample data in order to exemplify step 2.

#### Step 2: Identify redundant columns

Normalization is a complex design task. However, it can be guided by an analysis of unique values:

```
DT[, lapply(.SD, uniqueN)]
#   Product Class Class_2 Sales
#1:       3     2       2     4
```

If *redunancy is measured as percentage of duplicated values* this becomes:

```
DT[, lapply(.SD, function(x) 100 * (1 - uniqueN(x) / .N))]
#   Product Class Class_2 Sales
#1:      40    60      60    20
```

`Class` and `Class_2` are the columns with the highest share of duplicated values while `Sales` has the lowest redundancy.

The picture becomes clearer when looking at columns pair-wise:

```
rbindlist(
  lapply(
    combn(names(DT), 2L, simplify = FALSE),
    function(cols) data.table(t(cols),
                              N = uniqueN(DT, by = cols))
  )
)[order(N, V1, V2)][, redundancy := 100 * (1 - N / nrow(DT))][]
#        V1      V2 N redundancy
#1:   Class Class_2 3         40
#2: Product   Class 3         40
#3: Product Class_2 3         40
#4:   Class   Sales 5          0
#5: Class_2   Sales 5          0
#6: Product   Sales 5          0
```

So, in order to reduce overall redunancy, the data could be split up in one *product table* containing  `Class` and `Class_2` and in a second *sales table* containing `Sales` with `Product` as key column in both tables.

Note this is a makeshift approach which works for this simple example. It might look different for large tables with many columns.

#### Step 3: Separate the data

The two tables are created as follows

```
PT <- unique(DT[, -"Sales"])
PT
#   Product Class Class_2
#1:       A   Red   Large
#2:       B  Blue   Small
#3:       C  Blue   Large

ST <- DT[, c("Product", "Sales")]
ST
#   Product Sales
#1:       A    12
#2:       A    42
#3:       B    12
#4:       B    22
#5:       C    59
```

Note that `ST` must not be de-duplicated as it may contain single transactions.

#### Step 4: Combine data when needed

Now, `ST` can be used without the redundant information, e.g., for aggregation:

```
ST[, .(total_sales = sum(Sales)), by = Product]
#   Product total_sales
#1:       A          54
#2:       B          34
#3:       C          59
```

If the aggregated result should include the base data for each product it can be joined using `Product` as key:

```
ST[, .(total_sales = sum(Sales)), by = Product][PT, on = "Product"]
#   Product total_sales Class Class_2
#1:       A          54   Red   Large
#2:       B          34  Blue   Small
#3:       C          59  Blue   Large
```

If sales figures of all `Blue` products are requested, `PT` has to be filtered first and then joined with `ST` excluding then non matching rows:

```
PT[Class == "Blue"][ST, on = "Product", nomatch = 0]
#   Product Class Class_2 Sales
#1:       B  Blue   Small    12
#2:       B  Blue   Small    22
#3:       C  Blue   Large    59
```

If the top selling `Blue` products are to be shown this can be achieved by:

```
PT[Class == "Blue"][ST, on = "Product", nomatch = 0
                    ][, .(total_sales = sum(Sales)), by = .(Product, Class)
                      ][order(-total_sales)]
#   Product Class total_sales
#1:       C  Blue          59
#2:       B  Blue          34
```

Answer (score 1):

This gives the desired result using R:

```
df <- read.table(header=TRUE, sep="|", text=
'| Product | Class | Class 2 | Sales |
  | A       | Red   | Large   | 12    |
  | A       | Red   | Large   | 42    |
  | B       | Blue  | Small   | 12    |')[-c(1,6)]
unique(df[1:3])
# > unique(df[1:3])
#    Product   Class   Class.2
# 1  A         Red     Large   
# 3  B         Blue    Small 
df[,c("Product", "Sales")]
# > df[,c("Product", "Sales")]
#     Product Sales
# 1  A           12
# 2  A           42
# 3  B           12
```