# Subset data.frame vs data.table

Tags: r, subset

So I am about to make my first question here and I would like to apologise in advance for any mistake happen.

I encountered the following behaviour in R and I would appreciate any explanation why it is happening.

If I create a data frame like this (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43531957/normalise-dataframe-remove-data-redundancy-and-create-lookup-tables)):

```
DT <- fread(
  "| Product | Class | Class_2 | Sales |
| A       | Red   | Large   | 12    |
| A       | Red   | Large   | 42    |
| B       | Blue  | Small   | 12    |
| B       | Blue  | Small   | 22    |
| C       | Blue  | Large   | 59    |
",
  sep = "|"
)[, Product:Sales]

DT
#   Product Class Class_2 Sales
#1:       A   Red   Large    12
#2:       A   Red   Large    42
#3:       B  Blue   Small    12
#4:       B  Blue   Small    22
#5:       C  Blue   Large    59
```

Convert the data table to a data frame like :

```
DT<-as.data.frame(DT)
```

And try to identify redundant columns like in the post above using:

```
DT[, lapply(.SD, uniqueN)]
```

It gives me the following error:

```
Error in .subset(x, j) : invalid subscript type 'list'
```

I was trying to apply the solution of the above post to a data.frame for a while and I was getting the above error before I realised it was not possible because of the different object class.

Comment: Welcome to SO Harry. What is your question then? How to do `DT[, lapply(.SD, uniqueN)]` in `base R`, i.e. with `data.frame`s ?

Comment: `.SD` is a `data.table` function. It will not work on a data frame. The equivalent to work on a data frame would be `sapply(DT, function(i)length(unique(i)))` or simply `sapply(DT, uniqueN)`

Comment: @Sotos Thank you! That made it more clear.

Comment: @markus My question was why the combination of lapply and .SD doesn't work the same way in both cases.

Comment: @HarryKontop o.k. I asked because I thought you have figured that out as you wrote " I realised it was not possible because of the different object class."

Comment: @markus lol true, I probably din't express it very clearly. Sorry.. I thought I might need to use different syntax or smth because of the different class. I didn't now that the .SD function is exclusive of data.table.